# jQuery selector performance: by ID versus by tag with ID pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm pretty new to using jQuery and consequently I get along well enough to get the expected result but here's a question regarding performance, to which I'm not sure about the answer:

Which of the following selector is the most performant, assuming that the expected selection actually is a `<textarea>`?

- `$("textarea[id='someID']");`
- `$("#someID");`

Thx in advance!

Comment: Because selecting a single element by ID is a performance issue... `:P`

Comment: In my case, it is indeed not a performance issue... but should one wait until a performance issue has arisen before getting to know the best practices?

Comment: Use `$('#foo')` liberally, it's never an issue. Performance issues arise when performing queries within a loop. (Cache the query, `var $elems = $('.elems');`, and then use `$elems` in the loop.) Another performance issue are global queries on big pages. If your `.elems` elements are descendants of a `#foo` element, then `$('.elems', '#foo')` will perform much better than a global `$('.elems')` query. Also, avoid long chains, `$('.thing', '#wrapper')` performs better than `$('#wrapper ul li .thing')`. That pretty much covers it, I think. `:)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$("#someID");` would be much faster

Because it basically uses the standart javascript `document.getElementById` function

Comment: @PaulD.Waite If evidence is important, setup a perf. It's a pretty well known fact at this point that jQuery internally uses document.getElementByID when an id is passed in alone.

Comment: @Paul Take a look at the 'Sizzle' function in the jquery source

Comment: Not to mention it's not even worth setting up a jsperf to test selecting a single element, that would never be a performance bottleneck in well written code.

Comment: @KevinB While it may not be a bottle neck selecting a single element, it is an interesting comparison to see the outright speed (or lack thereof) of selectors when repeated x thousand times as JSPerf does.

Answer (score 4):

Selecting by `id` is always the fastest method as it uses javascripts own `getElementById` implementation.

[**JSPerf Demo**](http://jsperf.com/id-selector-vs-attribute-selector)

On my machine here (Win8, FF16.0.2) the attribute selector was **93% slower!!**

Answer (score 1):

The second selector will be faster as it directly maps to `document.getElementById`

You can check the results [here](http://jsperf.com/juqery-id-vs-id-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

For the fastest result, you have to wrap js getElementById in jquery object:

```
$(document.getElementById('myid'));
```

See http://jsperf.com/id-selector-vs-attribute-selector/3